.onChange it's not working when the value of @AppStorage changes
I've trying to do that ExecuteShortcutIntent changes viewModel wasExecuted to true, and then it would making the user defaults shortcutWasExecuted variable changes too, and then modify the ShortcutView due to @ObservedObject var viewModel and .onChange. but it turns out that onChange is not called, even that wasExecuted changes to true. Is there something wrong in the approach i'm trying to use? What I'm doing wrong?
public class ShortcutsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("shortcutWasExecuted") public var wasExecuted: Bool = false
}

struct ShortcutView: View {    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ShortcutsViewModel = ShortcutsViewModel()
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack(content: {
            Button(intent: ExecuteShortcutIntent(shortcutId: shortcutViewData!.id)) {
                Image(shortcutViewData!.icon, bundle: .main)
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(uiColor: ShortcutColors.getColor(colorString: shortcutViewData!.color)))
                    .frame(width: iconWidth, height: iconHeight)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle(radius: 4))
            .tint(Color("ShortcutBackground", bundle: .main))
            .shadow(color: Color("ShortcutShadow", bundle: .main).opacity(shortcutBackgroundShadowOpacity), radius: shortcutBackgroundShadowRadius, x: 0, y: 0)
            .controlSize(shortcutButtonSize)            
            Text(shortcutViewData!.description)
                .foregroundStyle(Color("ShortcutDescription", bundle: .main))
                .lineLimit(2)
        })
        .frame(width: shortcutWidth)
        .onChange(of: viewModel.wasExecuted, {
            viewModel.executeShortcuts(shortcutId: shortcutViewData?.id)
        })
    }
}

struct ExecuteShortcutIntent: AppIntent {
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        let viewModel = ShortcutsViewModel()
        viewModel.wasExecuted = true
        
        return .result()
    }
}



Note, you should be using @StateObject private var viewModel = ShortcutsViewModel()
Also, in ExecuteShortcutIntent you are creating a
new let viewModel = ShortcutsViewModel() unrelated to any other every time the function is called.
Use a single source of truth.

Is AppStorage supposed to trigger changes when used inside a class the same way it does when used in a view?

AFAIK, @AppStorage is part of SwiftUI and is only for use in a View.

Remove ViewModel class that's what View struct is for. Put @AppStorage in that.

@workingdogsupportUkraine sorry, but i couldn't understand about "Also, in ExecuteShortcutIntent you are creating a new let viewModel = ShortcutsViewModel() unrelated to any other every time the function is called. Use a single source of truth". What do you mean? ShortcutsViewModel isn't already the single source of truth? I'm learning yet, so sorry for that

@JoakimDanielson I made some tests and it's worked, but I don't know if it's a good practice to use AppStorage inside a class, and not inside a view

@malhal got it!

My point is, use the
@StateObject private var viewModel = ShortcutsViewModel(),
that is, use the one an only viewModel,
not create a different one every time you call perform(). The viewModel inside the perform() has no relations to the one outside.
